# Proving $\mathbb{P}(X=Y)=0$ for independent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

If I assume that $\mathbb{P}(X=x)=\mathbb{P}(Y=x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ with $X$ and $Y$ independent random variables on the same probability space, does it follow that $\mathbb{P}(X=Y)=0$?
My reasoning went as follows: $\mathbb{P}(X=Y)=\sum_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{P}(X=x \space\cap\space Y=x)=\sum_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{P}(X=x)\mathbb{P}(Y=x)=\sum_{x\in\mathbb{R}}0=0$. However, I'm not sure that every concept that I have used here is applicable in the most general setting. Could anyone verify whether this proof is correct for all probability spaces?

Comment: I think your proof is correct only for discrete random variables, but for absolutely continuous random variables always true that $P(X=x) = 0$

Comment: In the case of continuous random variables, is it not always the case that the probability of two independent random variables being equal is zero? Edit: sorry, that's what you already said. In that case, how would I complete the proof formally?

Comment: sometimes it is easier to take your problem in more dimensions. Independence tells us that vector $(X,Y)$ has distribution $\mu_X \otimes \mu_Y$. Then by Fubini $\mathbb P(X=Y) = \int_{\mathbb R} \int_{x=y} d\mu_X(x) d\mu_Y(y) = \int_{\mathbb R} \mathbb P(X=y) d\mu_Y(y) = \int_{\mathbb R} 0 d\mu_Y(y) = 0$

Comment: I can see how that is a very elegant proof. Does that mean that the one I gave is incorrect, or at least incomplete?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $X,Y$ be real-random variables such that $\forall t \in \mathbb R$ we have $\mathbb P(X=t) = \mathbb P(Y=t) = 0$.

Firstly: $X,Y$ need not be continuous random variable in the sense of having density with respect to Lebesgue measure! Condition $\mathbb P(X=t)=0$ for any $t \in \mathbb R$ only ensures that the CDF of $X$ $($and $Y)$ is a continuous function $($since $F_X(t) - F_X(t-) = \mathbb P(X=t) = 0 )$. There are examples ( look for Cantor distribution ) of distribution with continuous CDF but without density function.

Having said that, let's prove the statement. It is worth mentioning that you only need one of those variables to have continuous CDF for it to work.

Since $X,Y$ are independent, the distribution function of rv $(X,Y)$ is $\mu_X \otimes \mu_Y$.

We have $\mathbb P(X=Y) = \mathbb P( (X,Y) \in \Delta )$, where $\Delta = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x=y \}$.

Then:

$$ \mathbb P(X=Y) = \int_\Delta d(\mu_X \otimes \mu_Y) = \int_\mathbb R \int_{ \{x=y \}} d\mu_X(x)d\mu_Y(y) = \int_\mathbb{R} \mathbb P(X=y) d\mu_Y(y) = 0 $$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are discrete random variables. If $\mathbb{P}(X=x)=\mathbb{P}(Y=x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, it violates the basic property of the probability density function that it should sum (or integrate to) to 1. Therefore, $X$ and $Y$ are continuous random variables.

For continuous random variables, the condition $\mathbb{P}(X=x)=\mathbb{P}(Y=x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ always holds. Therefore, that part does not add any information. However, we note that $\mathbb{P}(X=Y)=\mathbb{P}(X-Y=0)$. Since $X-Y$ is a continuous random variable, the probability is zero.

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling that something was off about the sum being zero. You concretely explained the problem.

Comment: But in fact it is $0$. You (in density case, however those variables need not have densities tho) should integrate only diagonal, which is of $\lambda_2 - 0$ measure

Comment: Yes, the result still is true, but not for the reason I gave. Clear answers from both of you, appreciated.

Comment: But @Geethu Joseph stated that it need not be true for continuous random variables that $\mathbb P(X=Y)$ is zero, whereas it obviously is.

Comment: I agree with Dominik Kutek. I corrected my answer!